# Conditional Dispatch in Action Creators

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'm performing basic validation inside a bound actions creator.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    onSomething: (props) => {
        if (performValidation(props)) {
            return { type: 'SOME_ACTION' };
        }
    }
};
```

If the validation fails and I don't return an action to dispatch I received the error.

> Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.

Is this expected? I can work around the issue by using a thunk but that seems overkill for non-async conditional dispatch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, thunks are the correct approach here.  When any action creator is bound, it is called and the output is passed straight to `dispatch`.  Putting conditional logic into a "plain" action creator means that it might return `undefined`, and thus do `dispatch(undefined)`.

So, if you need to conditionally dispatch, either don't use a bound action creator and handle the conditional logic in the component, or dispatch a thunk and keep the conditional logic in the thunk.  To me, this is a good use case for a thunk.

Comment: I figured as much. Shouldn't dispatch just ignore undefined. That would allow conditional dispatch like the above with no middleware required.

Comment: No. The contract for `dispatch()` is that anything other than a plain JS object reaching the reducer is considered to be an error, period.  Middleware can "teach" `dispatch` to accept non-plain-object values by either preventing them from reaching the reducers, or transforming them along the way.  `redux-thunk` looks for functions, calls them, and does not forward them along the middleware pipeline.  You could easily write a middleware to catch undefined values as well, but that's separate from the core store's API contract behavior.